# Django: cannot register model in admin panel

Tags: python, django

I've various models in my apps. However, there is this one that I cannot register so I can see it in the `admin panel`.

So in my `cart` app `admin.py` file, I can use:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Cart, CartItem

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Cart)
```

But not:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Cart, CartItem

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Cart, CartItem)
```

Because I get this error:

```
 File "/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/projects_envs/perfectcushion_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 26, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "/home/ogonzales/Escritorio/projects_envs/perfectcushion_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 81, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'CartItem' object has no attribute 'model'
```

**cart/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product

# Create your models here.

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id


class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**cart/views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from shop.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItem
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from order.models import Order, OrderItem




# Create your views here.

def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        request.session.create()  # it does not return anything. that is why `cart = request.session.create()` will not work
        cart = request.session.session_key
    return cart  # Ultimately return cart



def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        )

        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            quantity= 1,
            cart = cart,
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request, total = 0, counter = 0, cart_items = None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
        cart_items =  CartItem.objects.filter(cart = cart, active=True)

        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    stripe_total = int(total * 100)
    description = 'Perfect Cushion Shop - New Order'
    data_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        try:
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']
            email = request.POST['stripeEmail']
            billingName = request.POST['stripeBillingName']
            billingAddress1 = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressLine1']
            billingcity = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCity']
            billingPostcode = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressZip']
            billingCountry = request.POST['stripeBillingAddressCountry']
            shippingName = request.POST['stripeShippingName']
            shippingAddress1 = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressLine1']
            shippingcity = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressCity']
            shippingPostcode = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressZip']
            shippingCountry = request.POST['stripeShippingAddressCountryCode']

            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email = email,
                source = token
            )
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount = stripe_total,
                currency = 'pen',
                description = description,
                customer = customer.id
            )
            '''Creating the order'''
            try:
                order_details = Order.objects.create(
                    token = token,
                    total = total,
                    emailAddress = email,
                    billingName = billingName,
                    billingAddress1 = billingAddress1,
                    billingCity= billingcity,
                    billingPostCode= billingPostcode,
                    billingCountry = billingCountry,
                    shippingName = shippingName,
                    shippingAddress1 = shippingAddress1,
                    shippingCity=shippingcity,
                    shippingPostcode = shippingPostcode,
                    shippingCountry = shippingCountry
                )
                order_details.save()
                for order_item in cart_items:
                    oi = OrderItem.objects.create(
                        product = order_item.product.name,
                        quantity = order_item.quantity,
                        price = order_item.product.price,
                        order = order_details
                    )
                    oi.save()
                    print("La orden fue creada")
                    print("Esta es la orden")
                    print(str(oi))

                return redirect('order:thanks', order_details.id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            return False,e

    return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, total = total, counter = counter, data_key = data_key, stripe_total = stripe_total,
                                             description = description))


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id = product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart = cart)
    if cart_item.quantity > 1:
        cart_item.quantity -= 1
        cart_item.save()
    else:
        cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def full_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id = product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart = cart)
    cart_item.delete()

    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `admin.py` as

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Cart, CartItem

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Cart)
admin.site.register(CartItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call admin.site.register twice for the two models:

```
admin.site.register(Cart)
admin.site.register(CartItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do:

```
admin.site.register([Cart, CartItem])
```